# Comparer<T>.Create in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have created a Comparer in .Net 4.5:

```
public static Comparer<Room> RoomComparer = 
  Comparer<Room>.Create((a, b) => a.RoomId.CompareTo(b.RoomId))
```

How can i create Comparer in c# .NET 4.0?

Comment: probably you have to create your own class that inherits Comparer<Room> and override Compare method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following

```
public static class Comparer
{
    public static Comparer<T> Create<T>(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        if (comparison == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        return new ComparisonComparer<T>(comparison);
    }
    private sealed class ComparisonComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Comparison<T> comparison;
        public ComparisonComparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
        {
            this.comparison = comparison;
        }
        public override int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return comparison(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

like this

```
public static Comparer<Room> RoomComparer = 
  Comparer.Create<Room>((a, b) => a.RoomId.CompareTo(b.RoomId))
```

Comment: The generic type parameter should be on the `Comparer` type not the create method. `Comparer<Room>.Create(....)` instead of `Comparer.Create<Room>(....)`

Comment: @KevinBowersox You are speaking about standard method, while this post is about custom method (shown in the answer) for older NET version which has no standard method. And for the custom method the generic type argument is on custom `Create` method (apparently we cannot extend `Comparer<T>` class).

Answer (score 5):

```
public class RoomComparer: IComparer<Room>
{
    int Compare(Room a, Room b)  
    {
        return  (a == null && b == null) ? 0
            : (a == null) ? -1
            : (b == null) ? 1
            : a.RoomId.CompareTo(b.RoomId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Richard, you might consider updating your answer - the `(b == null)` case should really return `1`. Also I think the check `(a == null && b == null)` is better to be `a == b`.

Comment: Agree on `(b == null`).