# Natural Sorting of list of string in descending order C#

Tags: c#, sorting, c#-4.0, libraries

I would like to ask how to sort a `List<string>` in descending order using the [Natural Sort Comparer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22517/Natural-Sort-Comparer) library.

I would like to ask if you someone have use this library
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22517/Natural-Sort-Comparer
to sort a `List<string>`?

This is the code snippets for ascending

```
public List<string> contents = new List<string>{ "a,b,c,d,e,f" };
public void sorting()
{
   using (NaturalSortComparer comparer = new NaturalSortComparer())
   {
      contents.Sort(comparer);
   }
}
```

I'm able to make it work to sort as **ascending**, but not **descending**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Call it `NaturalDescendingComparer` and then reverse everything, for example change `if(y1.Length > x1.Length)` to `if(y1.Length < x1.Length)`. In `PartCompare` you need to revert the order of the compared variables, for example: `return y.CompareTo(x);`

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in feature to make the sorting descending. But you can implement a comparer to make it do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's implement a simple *extension method*:

```
  public static partial class ComparerExtensions {
    public static IComparer<T> Reverse<T>(this IComparer<T> comparer) {
      if (null == comparer)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

      return Comparer<T>.Create((left, right) => comparer.Compare(right, left));
    }
  }
```

Then you can reverse *any* comparer (`ICompare<T>`) you like:

```
 MyList.Sort(YourCustomComparer.Reverse());
```

In your case (a bit strange implmentation with comparer implementing `IDisposable`):

```
 using (var naturalComparer = new NaturalComparer()) {
   contents.Sort(naturalComparer.Reverse()); 
 }
```

**Edit:** In case of **C# 4.0** or earlier version (which doesn't have `Comparer<T>.Create`) we can implement the extension method like this:

```
  public static partial class ComparerExtensions {
    private sealed class ReversedComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
      private readonly IComparer<T> m_Comparer;

      public ReversedComparer(IComparer<T> comparer) {
        m_Comparer = comparer;
      }

      public int Compare(T x, T y) {
        return m_Comparer.Compare(y, x);
      }
    }

    public static IComparer<T> Reverse<T>(this IComparer<T> comparer) {
      if (null == comparer)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

      return new ReversedComparer<T>(comparer);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Sort` sorts *inplace* when `OrderByDescending` (*Linq* extensions) doesn't. And thus we have to add `ToList` which brings overhead: `MyList = MyList.OrderByDescending(...).ToList();` Another issue with *disposing* `NaturalComparer`

Comment: I think the cleanest approach is simply switching the argument order in `CompareTo`.

Comment: @InBetween: Thank you! What a blind I've made!

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I try to implement your suggestion, but the compiler tells me that `Create` is not a definition of  `Comparer<T>`

Comment: @Hikari: what is the *version* of c# you use, please? Is it **4.0** or less? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901435/comparert-create-in-net-4

Comment: @Dmitry : I use C# 4.0

Comment: @Hikari: I see; in this case we have to implement an interface manually (`ReversedComparer<T>` class)

Comment: @Dmitry: THANKKK YOUUU VERRRYY MUUUCCHHH (＾▽＾)
It workkssss.!! I wish i can hug youu right now....!!

Comment: This is a nice solution; a fun improvement to it would be to have the factory detect when its argument was another `ReversedComparer`, and return the underlying collection, but that scenario seems pretty rare so this would be more fun than practical.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. *Horrible, never do this*: use the ascending order and then simply call `Reverse()` method (I'm only listing this option as a warning because, believe it or not, I've seen it more than once in production code).
2. The good way: Implement an `IComparer<string>` that simply returns the negative of the "ascending" comparer (or switches the argument order) and pass it into your sorting method.

But nº2 is already built in the framework for you; its the extension method [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__):

```
var ss = new[] {"a1", "a03", ... }
var descending = ss.OrderByDescending(
    s => s,
    new NaturalComparer());
```

UPDATE: Your updated question seems to imply you want to use `List.Sort`. In that case the way to go is #2, `OrderBy` will not sort in place.

Comment: Since `contents.Sort(comparer);` sorts *inplace* it seems that you have to add `.ToList()`: `contents = contents.OrderBy(...).ToList();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ah... the requirement that you have to use `Sort` was not there initially. Then option nº2 still stands as valid.

Comment: `NaturalComparer` class implements `IDisposable` (yes, it's quite a *strange* implementation). Where it should be *disposed*?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Forget the dispose issue, it doesn't need to be disposed... beats me why the author decided this had to be an `IDisposable`; pretty sure he didn't really understand how memory management worked.

Comment: I note that *technically* it is not correct to implement an `IComparer` that simply swaps the sign of an underlying `IComparer` because `0x80000000` is a legal output of the comparison, but it cannot be made positive. The correct solution is to make an IComparer that returns 0 if the wrapped comparer returns 0, 1 if it returns a negative, and -1 if it returns a positive. Or, as you note, swap the order of the arguments.