# Sorting [numbers] listview didn't work correctly c#

Tags: c#

it can't sorting the values correctly :

[image: Added image instead of link]

I use this code :
http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/sort-a-listview-using-the-column-you-click-in-c/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help!

Comment: What a lazy question. From your image, they are sorted correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much *

Comment: In fact, they are correctly sorted. `"100" < "11"` (notice that they are strings), this is the same than `"baa" < "bb"`

Comment: It seems, you are looking for *Natural ordering* (i.e. `"1" < "2" < "9" < "100"`, please, note that we compare `string`s) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611279/natural-sorting-of-list-of-string-in-descending-order-c-sharp/53611474#53611474

Comment: Please see this picture to know my story :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1929yWXGkUtjJleYAKKsIP709W0NCPXlj

Comment: We already saw your picture. Did you saw our comments?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you I do not know much

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question, not linked to off-site.

Comment: you will have to go through the trouble of splitting `item_100` by `'_'`, converting the second half into an integer and sorting by the integer

Comment: oh no , I do not know how to enter the code in the post . I'm sorry

Comment: I need these '_' in the item

Comment: Thanks for all *

Comment: @LaithKaser use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54462513/edit) under your post

Comment: I did not say to remove the `_` I said to split the string. research `string.Split()`

Comment: Answered by Ivan Salo * Thanks to all from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your string compare method

```
// Treat as a string.
result = string_x.CompareTo(string_y);
```

to this one

```
result = CompareNumericStrings(string_x, string_y);
```

And Compare implementation. It is not ideal but it does AlphaNumericSorting.

```
public int CompareNumericStrings(object x, object y)
{
    string s1 = x as string;
    if (s1 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    string s2 = y as string;
    if (s2 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int len1 = s1.Length;
    int len2 = s2.Length;
    int marker1 = 0;
    int marker2 = 0;

    // Walk through two the strings with two markers.
    while (marker1 < len1 && marker2 < len2)
    {
        char ch1 = s1[marker1];
        char ch2 = s2[marker2];

        // Some buffers we can build up characters in for each chunk.
        char[] space1 = new char[len1];
        int loc1 = 0;
        char[] space2 = new char[len2];
        int loc2 = 0;

        // Walk through all following characters that are digits or
        // characters in BOTH strings starting at the appropriate marker.
        // Collect char arrays.
        do
        {
            space1[loc1++] = ch1;
            marker1++;

            if (marker1 < len1)
            {
                ch1 = s1[marker1];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch1) == char.IsDigit(space1[0]));

        do
        {
            space2[loc2++] = ch2;
            marker2++;

            if (marker2 < len2)
            {
                ch2 = s2[marker2];
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (char.IsDigit(ch2) == char.IsDigit(space2[0]));

        // If we have collected numbers, compare them numerically.
        // Otherwise, if we have strings, compare them alphabetically.
        string str1 = new string(space1);
        string str2 = new string(space2);

        int result;

        if (char.IsDigit(space1[0]) && char.IsDigit(space2[0]))
        {
            int thisNumericChunk = int.Parse(str1);
            int thatNumericChunk = int.Parse(str2);
            result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk);
        }
        else
        {
            result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
        }

        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Comment: Dear Ivan, thank you ...
But what do you think I will upload the project for you and you will fix it for me.
I will give you a useful answer *
this :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ybtrlan57d_uZ8FZ2n0ByF3h8SHzC38x

Comment: it is simple just do as i mentioned in the post

Comment: ok thanks, removed file

Comment: على كل حال شكراً لكم . أنا ضيف ثقيل عليكم فآسف جداً

Comment: Ivan Salo * Finally understanding and the process was successful * My thanks and appreciation to you

Comment: See the result : https://drive.google.com/open?id=160DxS0ItxLItj3xLgCzKPsJZ3MAE_1HE